# How can I make use of global variables in ES2015 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify, babeljs

I am using Gulp, Babelify and Browserify to compile ES2015 into ES5.

Folder structure:

```
project
  - js
    - level.js
    - main.js
```

If I have the below defined module:

```
// level.js
var level = [];

level[0] = {
    name: 'level1',
    grid: {
        width: GRID_WIDTH,
        height: GRID_HEIGHT
    }
};

export default level;
```

And then I have my main JavaScript file:

```
// main.js
import level from './level.js';

var siteGame = (function() {
    var GRID_WIDTH = 50,
        GRID_HEIGHT = 50;

    console.log(level);

}());
```

How can I make sure that GRID_WIDTH and GRID_HEIGHT are available inside level.js?

At the moment I get an error, advising that GRID_WIDTH is undefined (from level.js)

Comment: Simply, you don't. You *could* use Webpack with DefinePlugin if you really wanted, but its much better to instead work around this problem a different way such as requires.

Comment: Why did you make those variables local to the IIFE in `main.js`? Do you intend to keep them private, do you intend to use multiple different values (in multiple scopes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of modules is that each has their own scope. If you want to "inject" data into a module, either export a function from level.js that accepts the dimensions, constructs the array/object and returns it, or put the dimensions in their own module and import it in level.js

Answer (score 0):

You defined those variables inside a function - they live and die inside the btackets of this function and you cannot access them anywhere outside them. If you want to use those variables globally you can either -

1. Write them on the global window object as done in es5 - but is not very recommended for various reasons

   2. Create a module which exports an object with all the variables you want to be exposed in you're app that way you can import that module and get all the variables you need.

I really recommend the second option over the first one.

Comment: The issue with putting stuff on `window` is not really an issue to do with memory management, but rather an issue with encapsulation and side-effects; you can't guarantee that another script won't modify that `window` variable, nor can you guarantee that variable will be available at the time you use it. It also forces you to run all of your code in the browser or through `jsdom`/similar, which sucks for modern day web apps, which generally have some kind of NodeJS tooling.